# Uart receive interrupt serial port terminal for stm32

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt, uart

I've been trying to implement a kind of emulator for my code from serial port terminal. I am sending the data from the terminal with uart receive interrupts and saving the data to an array but I have to enter a few data and save it.

I want my uart function to wait for enter key and then proceed to the next function for next data. I couldn't figure out how to implement it and I don't want to use putchar or fscanf. How can I develop my code to work this way? I can't use while loop or if statements because I am using interrupts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code implementation can be very different depending on your hardware/software settings(e.g. UART peripheral setting, interrupt setting ...). Therefore, if you share your current settings and code implementation, I can give you a more accurate answer.

If you are using **HAL_UART_Receive_IT** for UART RX Interrupt, that's usually not a good idea. Becuase the CPU has to copy each character from the UART peripheral to memory one by one.

In general, using **RX DMA** is a way to reduce CPU load and make code implementation easier.

After enabling the RX DMA of your UART, refer to the code template below and try to implement it.

```
#define RxBuffSize    256

uint8_t RxBuff[RxBuffSize];

void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size)
{
    if (huart == &huart1)
    {   
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            if(RxBuff[i] == '\n'){
                // TODO something...
            }
        }
        HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, RxBuff, RxBuffSize);
        __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);
    }
}


int main(void){

    //
    //
    //

    HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, RxBuff, RxBuffSize);
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);

    //
    //
    //

}
```